# Entry only in the Strategy, if the previous color is different than the actual color

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am having some problems with using strategy.entry

```
//Condition
prev_color = hmacolor[1]
if (hmacolor == #00ccff and prev_color == #ff0055)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (hmacolor == #ff0055 and prev_color == #00ccff)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

I want to Entry only in the Strategy, if the previous color is different than the actual color.
Now I get an Alert for every candle, but I only want to get an alert if the color of the line changes.

I get an Alert for every candle, but I only want to get an alert if the color of the line changes. If it changes from red to green, it means Long, if it changes from green to red, it means Short Alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Condition    
if (hmacolor == #00ccff and hmacolor[1] != #00ccff)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (hmacolor == #ff0055 and hmacolor[1] != #ff0055)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?